# anyone know of a FireFox plugin that allows us to open a new link in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, plugins, browser-addons

does anyone know of a FireFox plugin that allows us to open a new link in Chrome?

I often have to open links from FireFox into Chrome (so basically currently I'd have to copy the url and go to chrome and paste it in which of course is pretty troublesome)

Comment: You can drag and drop the URL or the page icon from Firefox to Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-with/) let's you open links in your browser of choice.

Comment: i've installed that addon and restarted firefox, but when i right click a link there isn't that option..

Comment: i've installed the Open With However i do not know how do we even use it? is it accessible through a simple right click on any link?

Comment: Have you configured it?  You have to go to the add-ons configuration and set if up for which browsers to open with.  And if you want it to be available for right clicking on links then you will want to enable "Main context menu (links)".

Comment: ok cool its done now